# Laravel application doesn't start on PORT number on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I deployed my app on Cloud Run service of google. It shows error "Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
". I run this image on Cloud Shell to test, it still runs with PORT 8080 and bind 0.0.0.0, I can not find more error in log of cloud run. My project is laravel project. Please help me, how to find out more logs and debug this case.
[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5IRu.png)

[Port running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzR4Z.png)

Comment: What does your Container logic look like?  At the highest level, the contract is that your code will be called and supplied a value in an environment variable called PORT.  That is a port that you should TCP listen on as soon as your container starts.  It will provide the coupling to the incoming request that caused your Cloud Run instance to start.

Comment: Need more info. Can you please paste logs of your Cloud Run service? They should be available on the UI. Also please add more info on how you're testing on Cloud Shell. Instructions on how to locally test: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local

Comment: Hi @AhmetB-Google, Kolban.
My app includes php-fpm and nginx, i used supervisord to start they when run docker. it only one message from cloud run log, `2019-12-10 11:21:35.938 ICTUnlinking stale socket /var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock`. So, i dont think it's error. I've checked base link like you sent, it's okie.

Comment: Your error message is standard one when the container failed to start. Paste your Cloud Run logs as requested by @AhmetB-Google

Comment: Did you do something like this to setup nginx to listen on PORT environment variable? .... https://itnext.io/running-any-container-on-cloudrun-cca137cddbca

Comment: @HoangThang as a last resort let's try this: Install `netstat` in your container image, `docker exec` into your container, run `netstat -ntlp`, paste its output to your question. I'm still suspecting your app isn't properly listening on 0.0.0.0:$PORT

Comment: @AhmetB-Google
https://imgur.com/a/VhD8B7L

Comment: @Kolban yes, i did like this when config nginx

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. When i run with supervisor at local it runs, but on Cloud Run it's not ok. So i've changed to entrypoint to start php-fpm and nginx, it's okie on Cloud Run

Comment: Can you provide more info? Next time you should provide more context, It would help to other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [step by step guide](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2019/10/get-laravel-6-running-on-google-cloud-run-step-by-step-with-ci/) that might help for this or similar problems with Laravel and Google Cloud Run.

Comment: that guide does not explain how to deal with the logs on laravel

Comment: and also does not explain how to deal with supervisor